# The rendered image has black dots

Tags: modeling, rendering, objects, particles, edit-mode

When making a cup i pressed something that make render with a lot of black dots,and i can't redo it

[image]

Comment: Show at least the full interface. Is the problem the shading mode? There is no information on the question to help us help you,  and it is not possible to infer what we're looking at on the picture.

Comment: how i will know were the problem is? i just pressed one button and that happend

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/